# Why is this one program, Anki, not accepting Japanese input?

Tags: ibus, mozc

I have a fresh install of Ubuntu 17.10. I have installed the latest version of the flashcard program Anki. I am using Mozc for Japanese input.

I have used Anki on Ubuntu computers in the past and never had a problem with Japanese input.

However, this time, even though Japanese works on every other program, it won't input in Anki. When I switch to Japanese input mode, the icon in my Gnome panel indicates I'm in Japanese input mode, but, whatever I type in any field in the Anki program just goes in directly as English characters.

How do I make Japanese possible for Anki the way it is for everything else?

Comment: https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=111087, https://www.reddit.com/r/i3wm/comments/429use/ibus_doesnt_work_in_qt_applications/?

Comment: Are you using `ibus`? Have you tried `fcitx` instead?

Comment: I'm having this problem on Kubuntu 20.04, anyone else?

Answer (score 0):

Although it seems this answer does not work for all people in all cases, this seems to have solved it for me.

I simply edited the ibus entry in startup applications to say:

```
ibus-daemon --xim
```

Comment: I tried this but it didn't work